# animated loading bar doesn't start at zero

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project that uses Django on the backend and Bootstrap on the frontend. I'm a noob when it comes to fronted, JS is black magic to me.

I need an animated loading bar that goes from 0% to 100% within X seconds. I managed to cobble something together that works, sometimes.

The problem is that the loading bar doesn't always start at 0%. It seems to start where ever it feels like starting, sometimes it even starts at 100%. The loading bar sits inside a modal that pops up when the user clicks a button.

After a clue from Boris K the actual question seems to be: How do I get the js running as soon as the modal opens.

Example of html file

```
<div class="modal fade" id="scanBanknote" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Scanning banknote</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please wait...
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var loading_time = 8
</script>
<script src="{%static 'js/progress_bar.js'%}"></script>
```

progress_bar.js

```
// loading time must be set in milliseconds, multiply by 1000
var loading_time = loading_time * 1000
$(".progress-bar").animate({width: "100%"}, loading_time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently trigger the animation directly when the page loads. Meaning that the animation starts when the modal is still hidden. Instead trigger the animation when the modal is shown.

You can find the different events for a modal in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#events).

In this scenario I went with:

> shown.bs.modal
>
> This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

```js
var loading_time = 8;

// loading time must be set in milliseconds, multiply by 1000
var loading_time = loading_time * 1000;

$("#scanBanknote").on("shown.bs.modal", function (event) {
  $(".progress-bar").animate({width: "100%"}, loading_time);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scanBanknote">
  Click Me
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="scanBanknote" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Scanning banknote</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please wait...
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since you say it's difficult to understand in a different context, here is how things might look when applied to your scenario:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="scanBanknote" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Scanning banknote</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please wait...
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{%static 'js/progress_bar.js'%}"></script>
<script>
    $("#scanBanknote").on("shown.bs.modal", () => initProgressBar(8));
</script>
```

progress_bar.js

```
function initProgressBar(loading_time) {
    // loading time must be set in milliseconds, multiply by 1000
    loading_time *= 1000;
    $(".progress-bar").animate({width: "100%"}, loading_time);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to post :-), but I found the animation didn't work properly unless you override the transition CSS .. `.progress .progress-bar {
    transition: none !important;
}`

Comment: See what I mean: https://codeply.com/p/ieqFfTgslB .. may related to Bootstrap version. I just wanted to make it known incase OP had the same issue

Comment: @Codeply-er I just ran them one after another, and the difference is pretty minor. The given CSS lets the progress bar fill up more linear. However the animation was already this way in the question, so I left it as is.

Comment: @Codeply-er I've modified your snippet to run them side by side. https://www.codeply.com/p/rmZTd1U3W5

Comment: @3limin4t0r I appreciate your effort to answer my question but it only makes it more difficult to understand when you change the context.

Comment: @CyberFly I've updated the question to make it more understandable. Although I don't understand why you set the `var loading_time = 8`. It's not in scope for `progress_bar.js` and needs to be set on `window`. Since the contents of `progress_bar.js` need to be wrapped in a function anyway (to not immediately trigger the progress bar animation), I've passed it as a parameter in my example.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm a total noob when it comes down to fronend development. You have helped me out a lot by putting the answer in context. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Click "Run code snippet" below. As you can see, the bar **Always** start at 0%.

Maybe, the animation starts when the page loads, be because the modal is hidden, you cannot see it until opened.

In that case, you have to run the `$(".progress-bar").animate` code only when the modal is opened

```js
var loading_time = 8
loading_time = loading_time * 1000

$(".progress-bar").animate({width: "100%"}, loading_time);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.progress {
  width: 500px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue. The loading bar starts running as soon as the page is loaded. So now the question is: how do I get it started when the modal pops up?

Comment: As said in my answer, you have to run the `$(".progress-bar").animate` code only when the modal is opened